# Create Constant At Run Time, But Access the Constant In Other Funcs

Tags: swift, variables, sprite-kit, constants

For the below code, I have a variable that is assigned a value in the didMoveToView func. After the value has been assigned, this variable will not change it's value again.

```
var myDevice: String!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    if frame.size.height == 480 {

        myDevice = "iPhone 4"

    } else if frame.size.height == 568 {

        myDevice = "iPhone5"

    } else {

        myDevice = "iPhone 6 or 6 plus"

    }

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    print(myDevice)

}
```

What I was hoping to do, is setup the variable as a constant instead, but be able to still access it through out the project. The problem with this is, if I set the variable as a constant, I can't then assign that constant with a value at run time.

I'm not 100% sure what the benefits are of having the value set as constant over a variable, but I feel like I can read the code a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, `private` allows access from all code in the same source file. You can make the setter private and the getter public like this:

```
private(set) public var myDevice: String!
```

Perhaps that is closer to what you want.

#### UPDATE

You can use `willSet` (even on a global variable), like this:

```
public var myDevice: String! {
    willSet {
        if myDevice != nil {
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}
```

You can only set it to a non-nil value once, and you cannot change it back to nil.

Comment: Is it a better way use enum ?

Comment: I don't see how an enum would be useful here.

Comment: I want this variable to become a constant once the value has been assigned, so I don't accidentally change the value later on down the track. From the test I've done on this answer, I'm still able to change the value.